# How to add custom parameters to pagination query

Tags: laravel, pagination

I want to add custom search parameters to the pagination link.

But it redirects to https://localhost:8000/customers?page=2

```
 $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->where($column, $operator, $num)
                ->where('email', 'LIKE', "%$key%")
                ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
                ->paginate(10);
```

I need this to be http://localhost:8000/customers?key=ang&role=&from=&to=&page=2

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#customizing-pagination-urls

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may append custom param in URL using appends method,

```
$users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->where($column, $operator, $num)
            ->where('email', 'LIKE', "%$key%")
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
            ->paginate(10)

$users->appends(['key' => 'ang']);
```

It would look like,

```
http://localhost:8000/customers?page=2&key=ang
```